# jQuery exception, probably AJAX-related for Autocomplete fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have an application running with jquery-1.5.2.min.js. It works fine in IE9, 8, 7, FF and Chrome.

But there's this problem. I have a JavaScript function in a custom .js file using jQuery that rules the behaviour of a hidden field. Whenever a button is clicked, the hidden field is turned into a jQuery Autocomplete control, and loads the Autocomplete information through an Ajax call. The function is like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{type: '" + control + "', param:" + params + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var dataTable = data;
            $(selector).autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: dataTable,
                open: function (e, ui) {
                    var options = $(this).data('autocomplete');

                    options.menu.element.find('a').each(function () {
                        var this_ = $(this);
                        var regex = new RegExp(options.term, "gi");
                        this_.html(this_.text().replace(regex, function (matched) {
                            return autocompleteTemplate.replace('%s', matched);
                        }));
                    });
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $(selector).val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        var options = $(this).data('autocomplete');
                        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                            valid = false;
                        options.menu.element.find('a').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                valid = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (!valid) {
                            if (control == "ProjectType") {
                                $('#selector').val("...");
                                $('#selector').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                $('#another.selector').val("");
                            }
                            // Remueve los valores inválidos.
                            $(this).val("");
                            $(selector).val("");
                            $(selector).data("autocomplete").term = "";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (control == "ProjectType") {
                        $('#selector').val("");
                    }
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(selector).val(ui.item.label);

                    $(hidden).val(ui.item.value);

                    if (control == "ProjectType") {
                        Autocomplete("ProjectSubType", action, ui.item.value);
                        // This is a function that changes the CSS for another HTML control
                        ProjectSubType(false);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So, whenever I change the browser type from IE8 to IE7 or IE9, or from IE7 to IE8 or IE9, after activating this field, the following exception is thrown from jquery-1.5.2.min.js

> Runtime error from Microsoft JScript: Cannot get value of property
>   'type': the object is null or undefined

FYI:

- The AJAX calls work. The autocomplete works properly and fires the events it has to fire when completed, in the order they have to be fired.
- There is another control that fires another AJAX event (filling a jqGrid) which produces no mistake.
- The conditional clause that you see in the code, "if (control == "ProjectType")", is meant to allow another control to turn into an Autocomplete if this control being used has an Autocomplete option filled in. Otherwise, it is disabled, as you can see (I changed its name to '#selector'). This also works properly: if you fill in a value in that Autocomplete, the other control is filled with the options needed.

Thanks

**UDP**

The function that calls the AJAX function is the following:

```
function SetSearchMenu(url, local) {
    $('#advancedSearch').hide();
    $('#advSearch').click(function () {
        if ($('#advancedSearch').css("display") == "none") {
            $('#advancedSearch').show();
            $('#generalSearch').val("...");
            $('#generalSearch').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            ProjectSubType(true);
        }
        else {
            $('#dAdvancedSearch').hide();
            $('#General').val("");
            $('#General').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        if (alreadyOpen == false) {
            Autocomplete("SelectorOne", url, null);
            Autocomplete("ProjectType", url, null);
            Autocomplete("Selector", url, local);
            alreadyOpen = true;
        }
    });
}
```

The parameters url and local are sent from the $(document).ready() function, and are filled with an @Url.Action() in string format and another variable hardcoded to one.

Comment: How do you get the value for control?  Maybe its because AJAX is async and control hasn't been set before the request was sent.. but is set after success which allows for you to access it

Comment: As far as I understand AJAX, the call isn't made until the function that contains the $.ajax() is called. The value for control is sent from another function, that which regulates the behaviour of this button, and is sent as a hardcode string.

Comment: Can you add the code your ajax is inside? and the other function that returns `control` value

Comment: So control = "SelectorOne","ProjectType",and "Selector" i'm guessing

Comment: That would be correct wirey. Anyway, I solved the problem: for some reason, after I had edited my .js file with that function, the program wasn't reading it correctly. It was behaving as though as the structure of the sentences from the .js file was still the same as before editing, only with the current code in place. I solved it by copying the code in a new .js file and eliminating the old one. Any idea why that could have happenned?